# How to set the color of bars in bar chart based on certain condition in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, bar-chart, conditional-formatting

[image]

Hi everyone,

Is there any way to use another color for the bars where the `count` is more than Average count (cell `E3`)? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Google sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SO36KvggYE6NgGAbvpbbB0qrhRLfBWMivRSUuOs6hNM/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You do it through a trick by splitting column C into two columns depending on the codition

E.g.

1. Type into `F3` `=Arrayformula(IF(C3:C190>E3,C3:C190,""))` and into `G3` `=Arrayformula(IF(C3:C190<=E3,C3:C190,""))`:

[image]

2. Modify your graph by replacing the series `C2:C190` by the two series `E2:E190` and `CF:F190`:

[image]